# Creation of a database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE
( Fname VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
Minit CHAR,
Lname VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
Ssn CHAR(9) NOT NULL,
Bdate DATE,
Address VARCHAR(30),
Sex CHAR,
Salary DECIMAL(10,2),
Super_ssn CHAR(9),
Dno INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Ssn),
FOREIGN KEY (Super_ssn) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(Ssn),
FOREIGN KEY (Dno) REFERENCES DEPARTMENT(Dnumber) );

CREATE TABLE DEPARTMENT
( Dname VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
Dnumber INT NOT NULL,
Mgr_ssn CHAR(9) NOT NULL,
Mgr_start_date DATE,
PRIMARY KEY (Dnumber),
UNIQUE (Dname),
FOREIGN KEY (Mgr_ssn) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(Ssn) );

CREATE TABLE DEPT_LOCATIONS
( Dnumber INT NOT NULL,
Dlocation VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Dnumber, Dlocation),
FOREIGN KEY (Dnumber) REFERENCES DEPARTMENT(Dnumber) );

CREATE TABLE PROJECT
( Pname VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
Pnumber INT NOT NULL,
Plocation VARCHAR(15),
Dnum INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Pnumber),
UNIQUE (Pname),
FOREIGN KEY (Dnum) REFERENCES DEPARTMENT(Dnumber) );

CREATE TABLE WORKS_ON
( Essn CHAR(9) NOT NULL,
Pno INT NOT NULL,
Hours DECIMAL(3,1) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Essn, Pno),
FOREIGN KEY (Essn) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(Ssn),
FOREIGN KEY (Pno) REFERENCES PROJECT(Pnumber) );

CREATE TABLE DEPENDENT
( Essn CHAR(9) NOT NULL,
Dependent_name VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
Sex CHAR,
Bdate DATE,
Relationship VARCHAR(8),
PRIMARY KEY (Essn, Dependent_name),
FOREIGN KEY (Essn) REFERENCES EMPLOYEE(Ssn) );
```

Here I am not able to create any table because each table is referencing to some other table using foreign key constraint.So kindly help me how to create the whole database.for eg. if I am creating EMPLOYEE table it is searching for DEPARTMENT table and not allowing to create the table and I trying to create DEPARTMENT then it is searching for EMPLOYEE table again not allowing the creation of the table.

Comment: first create all the tables and after that add the constraints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try to create and populate the tables without foreign key constraints and after that add the foreign key constraints.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the foreign keys separately when the tables have been created, e.g.

```
ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE ADD CONSTRAINT FK_EMPLOYEE_DEPARTMENT 
     FOREIGN KEY (Dno) REFERENCES DEPARTMENT(Dnumber);
```

Comment: It is allowing to create the table but not allowing to insert.

Comment: @AnujGarg, you need to come up with a different model. Your current model says that an employee must reference a department, but at the same time you are saying that a department must reference an employee (through the mgr_ssn). There is an inherent flaw in that design. You can overcome this by removing the manager data from the Department table, e.g. by adding a DepartmentManager table. This would also allow you to keep a history over the managers of departments over time, plus it would enable you to insert valid data. You might have more of these problems in your model, I haven't checked.

Comment: This model is given in the text book NAVATHE. Then how come it is having any flaws.And according to you even if it is having some flaws can you please sort it out.

Comment: It's definitely not a right design/model cause it depicts a circular chain between employee and department.

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution is remove the FK to `DEPARTMENT` (the below one) from creation of `EMPLOYEE` table and create all your tables/schema.

```
FOREIGN KEY (Dno) REFERENCES DEPARTMENT(Dnumber)
```

After then, recreate this FK on `EMPLOYEE` table saying

```
ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE ADD CONSTRAINT fk_emp 
FOREIGN KEY (Dno) REFERENCES DEPARTMENT(Dnumber);
```

See a successful Table creation Demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/410ce

Comment: Thank you Rahul its done but it is not allowing to insert into table employee.